# Can I open Outlook from VBA without elevated privileges, eventhough Word is opened with elevated privileges

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, office-automation, createobject

I ran into an issue with a VBA implementation in Word.

I would like to send an email upon the press of the Print button.

My code works fine when i open word without elevated privileges.
However, I need the document to be opened with elevated privileges.
And when I do so, the outlook app created is also opened with elevated privilieges, which works only when Outtlook is not currently running...
my guess is that since Outlook's already opened without being elevated ( and I can't change that ), the app that is being created with this line of code

```
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

interferes with the currently opened Outlook.

Do you know if it is possible to create an Outlook process within VBA in an elevated Word document, without it being elevated aswell?

Thank you.

Comment: Try using `Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")`. In this way it should use the existing session. If you want creation a new session (in case of not already open session) you should check `If olApp Is Nothing then olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`. Anyhow, being an object, the code you show should not work if not having `Set`. I suppose it is only a typo...

Comment: Yes, only a typo, sorry.

Comment: And using my above suggestion, does it open the existing session?

Comment: I did try to use GetObject, but i get error 429 ActiveX Component Cant Create Object.
I assume that this i because Outlook is opened without privileges, and that a Word opened with privileges can not see none elevated running apps, but this is a wild guess...

Comment: Theoretically, it shouldn't care about privileges of the calling application. But, when you tried, **are you sure that an Outlook session was open**?

Comment: 100% sure, yep, tried both with elevated and none elevated, with ekevated GetObject(,"Outlook.Application") does work, but not when opening with privileges.

Comment: However, opening Outlook from the Word with privileges using CreateObject works when Outlook is not already opened, but when I try opening Outlook while the code has been executed and the Word is still opened, i get prompted an error telling me that I can't open Outlook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Outlook is a singleton, you cannot open more than once instance of Outlook for a given local user.

And if the security contexts differ, COM system refuses to marshal calls between two apps, so this is not even Outlook specific.